# Java spark transform file

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a input  file test.csv :

```
a
b
c
d
```

My output file shoud be :

```
a|b|c|d|
```

How can do it on java spark?

Answer (score 1):

Java 8:

```
Dataset<Row> ds = session.read().csv("file");
Encoder<String> stringEncoder = Encoders.STRING();

ds
  .map(r -> r.getString(0), stringEncoder)
  . groupByKey(r -> "", stringEncoder)
  .mapGroups((key, values) -> {
      Iterable<String> vals = () -> values;
      return String.join("|", vals);
  }, stringEncoder)
  .repartition(1) // if you want to have single file
  .write()
  .csv("out");
```

I'm not sure if you want `|` after last element, if yes you can modify `return` in `mapGroups` to: `return String.join("|", vals) + "|";`

Java 7:

```
ds
    .map(new MapFunction<Row, String>() {
        public String call(Row value) throws Exception {
           return value.getString(0);
        }
    }, stringEncoder)
    .groupByKey(new MapFunction<String, String>() {
        public String call(String value) throws Exception {
            return "";
        }
    }, stringEncoder)
    .mapGroups(new MapGroupsFunction<String, String, String>() {
        public String call(String key, Iterator<String> values) throws Exception {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if(values.hasNext())
                sb.append(values.next());
            while(values.hasNext()) {
                sb.append("|");
                sb.append(values.next());
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
   }, stringEncoder)
  .repartition(1) // if you want to have single file
  .write()
  .csv("out");
```

Similarly, if you need `|` after last element you can modify `mapGroups` to:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 while(values.hasNext()) {
    sb.append(values.next());
    sb.append("|");
 }
 return sb.toString();
```

In Scala it is even easier:

```
val ds = session.read.csv("src/main/resources/t.csv")

ds
   .map(r => r.getString(0))
   .groupByKey(_ => 1)
   .mapGroups{case (_, elems) =>
      elems.mkString("|")
   }
   .repartition(1)
   .write
   .csv("out")
```

Comment: Hello Piotr Kalanski, Thanks for responding. But my spark's version is 1.5.2 so i can't use sparksession. Can you help me please;

Comment: Hi @baba in Spark 1.5.2 you can use spark-csv library for reading/writing csv (https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) please look at example for Spark 1.4, you just need to use SQLContext instead of SparkSession.